# sed - perform only first (nth) matched replacement?

Tags: bash, sed

Consider I have the following file:

```
echo "1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
" > ztest
```

Here I'd like to change only the first `1` into `5` and leave everything else intact.

I know `sed` has a `quit` command - so I'm trying the following:

```
$ sed 's/1/{5;q}/' ztest 
{5;q}
2
3
4
{5;q}
2
3
4
{5;q}
2
3
4
{5;q}
2
3
4
```

This changes all lines, so it's no good. So, then I try this:

```
$ sed '{s/1/5/;q}' ztest 
5
```

Now, this apparently does as requested - changes the first line and exits; however, I'd like the rest of the lines intact! (*since this, basically has the effect of replacing the entire file with a single '5'*)

So I'm at a loss at what kind of syntax is needed? Note that I need this to change an "early" line in a gigabyte file inline (using `sed -i`); thus I'd like `sed` to only search and replace in the first brief section - and after that, output lines unchanged (*since `sed -i` anyways dumps into a temp file first, and then overwrites the original*); hoping to save some processing time.

Thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

EDIT: forgot subquestion: is it possible to extend this to first n matches? (say, in the file above, first two '1's are changed to 5 - rest of it is output verbatim?)

Comment: Are you stuck with `sed` only?

Comment: HI @Mat - not really; just the first one I resort to when I have t replace inline in text files - any other suggestions are welcome!

Comment: same situation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file)

Comment: Many thanks for that link, @selman - I like the trick with line 0 (_as in `0,/Apple/{s/Apple/Banana/}`_) from there - cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have seen it somewhere else on this site:

```
sed '/1/{s/1/5/;:a;n;ba}' ztest
```

So once you found the 1st occurrence, you loop till the end of the file reading and printing lines.

**Update**

It can be enhance to only replace the Nth match.  The idea is to store a `X` at each match in the holdspace, and when all the `X`s are there, loop till the end of file.  Bellow, the script that replace the 2nd occurrence:

```
sed '/1/{G;s/\nX\{1\}//;tend;x;s/^/X/;x;P;d};p;d;:end;s/1/5/;:a;n;ba'
```

Note that you need to put (N-1) between the `\{` and `\}`.

**Update 2**

I realize that the `P;d` above is useless if the `p;d` is replaced by `P;d`.  So a simpler solution is:

```
sed '/1/{G;s/\nX\{1\}//;tend;x;s/^/X/;x};P;d;:end;s/1/5/;:a;n;ba'
```

Comment: Many thanks for that @jfgagne - I was hoping `sed` can refer to the n-th match; and glad to see an example (I'll need to brush up on my `sed` syntax, though :) ) Cheers!

Comment: One caveat.  The OS/X (even on El Capitan) sed command doesn't recognize { } and will just punt with following error message: `sed: 1: "/1/{s/1/5/;:a;n;ba}": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)`

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if that's doable with `sed`, but here's an `awk` version.

```
awk 'BEGIN {matches=0}
     matches < 2 && /1/ { sub(/1/,"5"); matches++ }
     { print $0 }' ztest
```

This will replace `1` with `5` for the first two matches of `1`. (Change the `2` in there to increase/decrease the number of matches you want.)
After that, the file is printed as-is.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @Mat - by the way, your original `sed` answer led me [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/394291/39752); but I think I like the direct number of matches specification better. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '0,/1/s//5/' file
```

Comment: Thanks @potong, care to explain a bit more please?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Mat's first answer (over at StackOverflow, now deleted), the syntax for `sed` to replace only the match on first line is:

```
sed  '1s/1/5/' ztest
```

However, you have to know explicitly the line number where to perform the match.

So if I know the file is as above, then the first two `1`'s appear on lines 1 and 5; so for the first two matches, I could instruct `sed` to apply the expression between lines 1 and (say) 6 - the syntax for line (address) range in `sed` being a comma (`,`):

```
$ sed  '1,6s/1/5/' ztest
5
2
3
4
5
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

Similarly, second and third occurrence of `1` are on lines 5 and 9 - so I can similarly use the range, say, from line 3 to line 10 to change second and third occurrence of `1`:

```
$ sed  '3,10s/1/5/' ztest
1
2
3
4
5
2
3
4
5
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

.... which I guess answers my question in terms of `sed`; although I hoped that I could specify the number of matches directly (*as in the `awk` solution by  [@Mat](https://superuser.com/a/394283/39752)*).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:a;n;ba` pattern once again:

```
$ sed '/1/{s//5/;:A;/1/{s//5/;:B;n;bB};n;bA}'
```

Answer (score -3):

Use simply this:
sed 's/1/5/' ztest